# How to bind observable collection datagrid with textbox on double click?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm learning WPF using MVVM.

I have a DataGrid which contains some information. The source of the data gird is a observable collection. 
I need to load the Information  into  textbox when I double click on a particular row in the datagrid. I want the row's particular cell should be loaded into the textbox.

Steps I followed

1. Declared a Datagrid

Window.xaml :

```
     <DataGrid x:Name="datagrid1" SelectedItem="{Binding GetRowData}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="False"
Height="90" Width="358" Margin="-210,-200,-90,-187" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <DataGrid.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding modelclasswithcombobox}"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding isfront}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding ModelClasstabwithdate}"/>
                       </DataTrigger>
                     </Style.Triggers>
                   </Style>
           </DataGrid.Style>
    </DataGrid>
```

2. Declared a textbox

In the textbox I binded the selected item of datagrid  as a path.

```
 <TextBox x:Name="txtboxAuditId" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}" 
  Width="108" Height="19.277" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
 Margin="-20,14,708.962,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="{Binding 
 ElementName=datagrid1, Path =  GetRowData, Mode=TwoWay, 
 ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,NotifyOnValidationError=True, 
 UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" />
```

3. In the viewmodel Declared a property with INotifyPropertyChanged to get the  changed data.

   ```
   private string _gettherow;
   public string GetRowData
   {
       get { return this._gettherow; }
       set
       {
           if (this._gettherow != value)
           {
               this._gettherow = value;
               OnPropertyChanged("GetRowData");
           }
        }
   }
   ```

Now the question is how to provide the command on when I click the datagrid row so that my textbox is populated. I usually use the  Icommand interface for button click event whether here also I need to apply the same or anything else.

Comment: Is this any help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18595654/wpf-datagrid-double-click-cell-mvvm-design

Comment: Do you want to place TextBox inside the DataGrid's cell? Or a stand alone TextBox?

Comment: Textbox is standalone. Just when i click the datarid cell or row, i want the the required cell value to be loaded into the textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your GetRowData should not be string in this case. It should be your custom type, like your ObservableCollection. For example, if below is your ObservableCollection which is bound to the DataGrid,

```
ObservableCollection<ModelClass> collection = new ObservableCollection<ModelClass>();
```

Then your GetRowData should be like this.

```
private ModelClass _gettherow;
public ModelClass GetRowData
{
    get { return this._gettherow; }
    set
    {
        if (this._gettherow != value)
        {
            this._gettherow = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("GetRowData");
        }
     }
}
```

Then bind it to TextBox like this (CustomType.PropertyName)

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding GetRowData.Name}"/>
```

Comment: Though it doesn't provided solution on double click. It helped me understand on how to bind the datagrid with textbox. Thanks.

Comment: @Vini It should work on double click, since the SelectedItem will be changed on double click. Whats the issue you faced?

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand the question, you want to update an independent `TextBox` when the user has entered your `DataGrid` `Cell` or `Row`.

If that's the case, then you want to use `DataTriggers`

Something to the effect of

```
        <TextBox>
            <TextBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=yourDataGrid, Path=BeginningEdit}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding YourTextProperty}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Style>
        </TextBox>
```

You can read more about it here https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/styles/trigger-datatrigger-event-trigger/